# Set visibility for an image within a ListView row

Tags: android, listview

**Overview**:

I have a ListView with a custom adapter/layout, every time a user adds a new row (which contains a number), I check if that number is the smallest in the list. If so, an image within that row must be set as visible while setting all other row's images as invisible.

**Problem**:

My ListView does not set any row's image as visible, even though I have the index of the smallest element.

**How I'm doing it**:

```
//In MainActivity

private void addProduct(float price) { //User adds product
    priceList.add(price); //Add to Float list
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    updateView(findMinIndex(priceList)); //Find smallest val indx
}

private void updateView(int index){

    View v = listView.getChildAt(index -
            listView.getFirstVisiblePosition());

    if(v == null)
        return;

    ImageView checkMark = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.check_mark);
    checkMark.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //Initially set Invisible
}
```

**Edit, CustomAdapter:**

```
public CustomList(Activity context,
                      ArrayList<Float> priceList) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_single, priceList);
    this.context = context;
    priceList = priceList;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);
    TextView price = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.new_price);
    ImageView cheapest = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.check_mark);

    price.setText(priceList.get(position) + "");

    return rowView;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: what is v ? and post your activity class and adapter as well

Comment: v is the View that I'm trying to set the image as visible for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working :).

Problem is that adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); is async, so while it's doing that, updateView(findMinIndex(priceList)); runs but doesn't find the new row as it should. Therefore, I add a runnable to the ListView object as so:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
listView.post( new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        updateView(findMinIdx(priceList));
    }
});
```

Now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

It is your priceList binded with the adapter?
First of all i would put a breakpoint to see if you are getting the right view in the updateView method.

Comment: Yes it is, and view is only returned when the new value I enter is higher than  others. Also, no view is returned when I enter the very first row.

Answer (score 0):

try this way;

- Create a Pojo class with imageview and it's state(Visibility) initially set all to invisible

  Add your items to the ArrayList of Pojo Class type.

  when user enters a new row based on your requirement set visibility state to true or false(visible or invisible) and call notifyDataSetChanged() to the adapter.

  Doing this way you can have a easy  track of the items.